# Playing skyrim cannot join Dark brothethood

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed Grelod the kind without talking to anyone from the brotherhood does this mean I cannot join?

Answer (score 3):

Have you already talked to Aventus Aretino? If you haven't go talk to him and complete the job. If you go to sleep afterwards you'll wake up in the abandoned shack in the swamp near solitude.